# How to generate combinations of elements of different lists?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have a list of lists that goes like

```
[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7,8]]
```

I want to create a program/function that creates a combinations like

```
1,3,5
1,3,6
1,3,7
1,3,8
1,4,5
1,4,6
.
.
.
```

If there's a way you can do it without using the itertools module, that would be even more appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use the itertools module, since the `product` is exactly for that. And any implementation you do, is basically already done in itertools `product`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: You could've at least used the itertools module to find out the proper name, and then it would've been easy to find it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked for a solution **without** `itertools`, this one is a recursive function that takes a list of any length and does the combination you need:

```py
def combine(elems):
    if len(elems) == 0:
        return [[]]
    result = []    
    subcombinations =  combine(elems[1:])
    for x in elems[0]:
        for y in subcombinations:
            result.append([x, *y])
    return result
```

Or a much shorter version

```py
def combine(elems):
    if len(elems) == 0:
        return [[]]
    return [[x, *y] for x in elems[0] for y in combine(elems[1:])]
```

Comment: If you want short, you could do `if not elems: return [[]]`. Also wouldn't crash for an empty input then.

Answer (score 3):

you can use  [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7,8]]
list(itertools.product(*a))
#output
[(1, 3, 5),
 (1, 3, 6),
 (1, 3, 7),
 (1, 3, 8),
 (1, 4, 5),
 (1, 4, 6),
 (1, 4, 7),
 (1, 4, 8),
 (1, 5, 5),
 (1, 5, 6),
 (1, 5, 7),
 (1, 5, 8),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (2, 3, 6),
 (2, 3, 7),
 (2, 3, 8),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (2, 4, 6),
 (2, 4, 7),
 (2, 4, 8),
 (2, 5, 5),
 (2, 5, 6),
 (2, 5, 7),
 (2, 5, 8),
 (3, 3, 5),
 (3, 3, 6),
 (3, 3, 7),
 (3, 3, 8),
 (3, 4, 5),
 (3, 4, 6),
 (3, 4, 7),
 (3, 4, 8),
 (3, 5, 5),
 (3, 5, 6),
 (3, 5, 7),
 (3, 5, 8)]
```

Comment: This is the best solution – especially since you can use the iterator as a generator...

Comment: @ybressler_simon You mean as an *iterator*?

Comment: Whoops. ***You can use the generator as an iterator...*** @KellyBundy

Comment: @ybressler_simon There's no generator here, just an iterator. See the documentation or [try some tests](https://tio.run/##ZY7BSgNBDIbv8xS5dUdCQddqKXj2IZY9TMfZNbCdDJkIFfHZt2mrq9Bcws/3kfzlU985t9si80yHwqJAmkSZp@oG4QNEnqYUlTjXddhH@LFeU04SlOVqUa7FrF9KdVy4C/ACXXePD9j22LX4iBvbG3zCZ9z2vSvGl6frIvz2EbW5C96NRpojDCxwtBdQvHPnQHpJCOPOgU0RytqQ@n9pWH1RtVoackzG8K@yt7Pfqxt5qXy@dKP4eT4B).

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks for pointing that out. @KellyBundy

Answer (score 1):

This is a roughly equivalent implementation of `itertools.product()` from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in case you want/need to build the function without using a library.

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)

a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7,8]]

print(list(product(*a)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 5), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 5), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 3, 5), (3, 3, 6), (3, 3, 7), (3, 3, 8), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 5, 5), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8)]
```

To print as you wish:

```
results = list(product(*a))

print('\n'.join([','.join(list(map(str, res))) for res in results]))
```

Output:

```
1,3,5
1,3,6
1,3,7
1,3,8
1,4,5
1,4,6
1,4,7
1,4,8
1,5,5
1,5,6
1,5,7
1,5,8
2,3,5
2,3,6
2,3,7
2,3,8
2,4,5
2,4,6
2,4,7
2,4,8
2,5,5
2,5,6
2,5,7
2,5,8
3,3,5
3,3,6
3,3,7
3,3,8
3,4,5
3,4,6
3,4,7
3,4,8
3,5,5
3,5,6
3,5,7
3,5,8
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into linear list and use combinations

```py
from itertools import combinations
linearArr = [ele for ele in row for row in [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7,8]]]
for comb in combinations(linearArr,3):
    print(comb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a [recursive function](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/):

```
def comb(arrs, i=0, numbs=[]):
    if i == len(arrs):
        print(*numbs)
        return
    for j in arrs[i]:
        comb(arrs, i + 1, numbs + [j])

arrs = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7,8]]
comb(arrs)
```

Output:

```
1 3 5
1 3 6
1 3 7
1 3 8
1 4 5
1 4 6
1 4 7
1 4 8
1 5 5
1 5 6
1 5 7
1 5 8
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 3 7
2 3 8
2 4 5
2 4 6
2 4 7
2 4 8
2 5 5
2 5 6
2 5 7
2 5 8
3 3 5
3 3 6
3 3 7
3 3 8
3 4 5
3 4 6
3 4 7
3 4 8
3 5 5
3 5 6
3 5 7
3 5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried two different ways, straight list comprehension and a recursive function.

The list comprehension method is the simplest but assumes your list will only have 3 elements.  If you add a fourth set of numbers to your main list, the list comprehension will need to be adjusted to work with it.

In contrast the recursive function is more complicated but will handle an unlimited list of lists with the sub-lists having any number of elements.  Of course, it's recursive so a limit will be reached and the time it takes to process the list of lists will be exponentially greater with each additonal list of numbers.

## List Comprehension

```py
lol = [
    [1,2,3],
    [3,4,5],
    [5,6,7,8]
]
o = [[x, y, z] for x in lol[0] for y in lol[1] for z in lol[2]]
print(repr(o))
```

### output

```py
[
  [1, 3, 5],
  [1, 3, 6],
  [1, 3, 7],
  [1, 3, 8],
  [1, 4, 5],
  ...
  [3, 5, 6],
  [3, 5, 7],
  [3, 5, 8]
]
```

## Recursive function

```py
def stich(l: list) -> list:
    def merge(a, b):
        if not a:
            return [[y,] for y in b]
        return [x + [y,] for x in a for y in b]
    ol = []
    tl = l.copy()
    while tl:
        ol = merge(ol, tl.pop(0))
    return ol


stiched_list = stich(lol)
print(repr(stiched_list))
```

### output

```py
[
  [1, 3, 5],
  [1, 3, 6],
  [1, 3, 7],
  [1, 3, 8],
  [1, 4, 5],
  ...
  [3, 5, 6],
  [3, 5, 7],
  [3, 5, 8]
]
```

Comment: Your "recursive function" is not recursive.

Comment: I think you'll find that it is... It's just wrapped in a non-recursive function